# Android studio Arctic : layout design view shows nothing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So i updated to android studio arctic with AGB 7.0 .

Design view for layout won't show anything and component tree showing "Nothing to show".

1. compileOptions is set to java 11.
2. have tried clearing sdk folder and re-installing platform-tools again.
3. gradlePlugin version is 7.0.2
4. gradle wrapperas 7.0.2.
5. Tried invalidate cache and restart.
6. tried re-installing android studio.

Build would always succeed and app would run at emulator and device without any issue.

[image]

Would appreciate any help here...have tried almost all solutions present in stackoverflow :(

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate and restart android studio ?

Comment: first thing to do for any issue with android studio...:) already tried..

Comment: Try `Build> Clean`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like android arctic has some issues with design view...if anyone facing this i would advise to use bumbleBee android studio.